# How we can store CMTimeRange into NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I need to store CMTimeRange of different videos in array later i will merge these videos.

please answer if anybody know about it.any answer will be appreciated.....

Answer (score 1):

Use [CMTimeRangeCopyAsDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTimeRange/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_8) to create a `CFDictionaryRef` from your CMTimeRange, and use `CMTimeRangeMakeFromDictionary` to get your `CMTimeRange` back from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use the `CMTimeRangeCopyAsDictionary` function and save an array of dictionaries or failing that, you could save each time range using `NSValue` perhaps?